# Uniform convergence disprove

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Why the sequence of functions $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{nx+1}$ is not uniform convergent in (0,1)? I've already prove the pointwise convergence but I can't justify why this sequence is no uniform convergent.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/561737/uniform-convergence-of-a-family-of-functions-on-0-1?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uniform convergence of a family of functions on $(0,1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/561737/uniform-convergence-of-a-family-of-functions-on-0-1)

Comment: Thanks by the link, but is not  the same sequence that one has 'x' in the numerator but the mine not.

Comment: Sorry, you are right.

Comment: Don't worry I'm glad by the advice, maybe I find thta problem in the near future

Comment: I don't know that I'd characterize the convergence as ["punctual"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/punctual) - it seems rather slow, all things considered! (The English term for this is "pointwise".)

Comment: @Chris Well, slow does not imply not punctual. You just need to get there on time.

Comment: @zhw Hmm. You've arrived at a good point! - although, you weren't entirely punctual in doing so....

Comment: @Chris True, I was not punctual with my comment, however I was pointwise convergent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

What happens when we take $x=1/n\in (0,1)$?

Comment: I'm not specially good with analisys but are you suggesting that can I take a subsequence in the domain such that the familiy doesn't cpnverges to zero?

Comment: For negating uniform convergence we need to find an $\epsilon>0$ (here we take $\epsilon=\frac12$) such that for all $N$ there exists an $n>N$ (here take any $n>N$) and an $x\in (0,1)$ (take $x=1/n$) such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\ge \epsilon$ (here $\frac{1}{1+nx}=\frac12 \ge \epsilon=\frac12$).

Answer (score 1):

These functions are uniformly convergent on $(\epsilon, 1)$ for any $\epsilon > 0$ but not on the whole interval $(0,1)$.